table chosen column at page horizontal center
I'd like to horizontally center a table based on its first column. In my example I have a two-column table, therefore i could add a column with the width of the second column on the left but I'm seeking for an easier solution (especially if there are more than 2 columns), if possible without tikz.
In other words, in my example I want the quotation being at the horizontal center of the page.

\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage {tabularray,lipsum}
\usepackage[verbose,hmargin=2cm,vmargin=3cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{center}
\begin{tblr}{colspec={lr},column{1}={font=\bfseries}}
  le courage n'est pas l'absence de peur \\
  mais la capacité de vaicre ce qui fait peur & N. Mandela \\
\end{tblr}
\end{center}

\lipsum[2]
\end{document}


I've take the liberty of adding the tags horizontal-spacing and tabularray.

Maybe, the verse package might interest you.

I suggest you switch to a 1-column setup and encase \hspace{1cm}\textmd{N. Mandela} at the end of row 2 in an \rlap ("rightward overlap") directive. (You're obviously free to choose an amount of horizontal spacing that differs from 1cm.) The argument of \rlap doesn't count toward the effective width of the 1-column tblr environment. If you want, you can think of \rlap -- and \llap ("leftward overlap") too -- as the horizontal equivalent of \smash.

\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{tabularray,lipsum}
\usepackage[verbose,hmargin=2cm,vmargin=3cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1][1-10]

\begin{center}
\begin{tblr}{colspec=l,column{1}={font=\bfseries}}
  le courage n'est pas l'absence de peur \\
  mais la capacité de vaicre ce qui fait peur%
    \rlap{\hspace{1cm}\textmd{N. Mandela}} 
\end{tblr}
\end{center}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}


Addendum: Here's the result of a nearly identical setup, except that now the column contents are centered horizontally (via colspec=c) instead of left-aligned. IMNSHO, centering looks better, at least for a two-row table.


Aside: I think the tabular material would look better if the cells were centered rather than left-aligned.

go head... let's see if it's better looking

@user1850133 - Please see the addendum I posted.
